# Measurement units for axes of ACF and PACF plots in R

Tags: r, autocorrelation

I'm new to the whole programming on R thing, and I've hit a wall. 
I'm trying to set up forecasts using using a GARCH while controlling for seasonality using a Fourier series as an external regressor. Using 672 data points, with the data recorded every half-hour over the course of the day, I've set up the code up like this:

```
n=672
garch.spec=ugarchspec(variance.model=list(model="sGARCH",garchOrder=c(2,2)),mean.model = list(armaOrder=c(1,1),include.mean=TRUE,external.regressors=fourier(y, K=11)))
fit11=ugarchfit(garch.spec,data=ts(solar,start=1,end=14,f=48),solver="nloptr")
```

Which works but... the ACF and PACF look like this:

[image]

Which actually isn't that bad, except that I've only 672 data points but my ACF and PACF lags are 2,500,000+. Does this make sense/I've no idea how to fix this, and would be grateful for any help whatsoever:)

Comment: **(1)** Are you asking how to improve the model? **(2)** Also, I suppose you are examining the *standardized* residuals from the ARMA-GARCH model. But then the confidence bounds in the graphs may be misleading because the null distribution of ACF and PACF differs depending on whether you supply raw data (the standard null distribution) or model residuals (slightly different null distribution). **(3)** Finally, how does the title of the question match its contents?

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't more clear. No, not so much improving the model, more like how can I possibly have 500,000 lags with 672 observations?

Comment: Oh, that is just a feature of R. Lags are measured in terms of periods rather than units. You must have specified a funny period for your time series. Don't pay too much attention to the axes.